# Breeze does not support sending the displayName as metadata

Tags: metadata, breeze

One of the things why really enjoy working with Breeze is because I have a lot of freedom regarding the metadata, and I use this freedom to manually provide an entity model, including validators. This works great, but when it comes to localizing the messages for the standard validators, I noticed that they use the property names instead of the display names, and this was because I set the display names after the metadata was loaded from server. Well, the thing is that I want to avoid a second call to server just to get the display names. As a temporary solution, I changed the breeze code to allow getting the displayName also from the metadata sent from server, but then again, I do not like changing the breeze sources.

Is there any other way of getting the metadata in one call and provide it to breeze? Naturally, other information like Description or Watermark would be welcome.

The latest versions provide a custom node, which I could use, but then I need some sort of interceptor for each property, where I take the display name and set it to the data and navigation properties. Is there a way to do this?

Remarks: I have a pull request on github for the breeze project, the changes are minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you've read about Breeze's "custom" metadata support: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-metadata

If so, then all you need to do is create a custom endpoint on the server that creates json in the 'custom metadata' format (you will probably use reflection on the server to collect this data), and return this json to the client and then call

```
myMetadataStore.importMetadata(customMetadataFromServer, true);
```

Comment: actually I use the standard breeze way to get metadata, (Metadata method in controller, the metadata properly formatted as breeze expects, according to the schema), but I thought because the displayName is anyway present in the DataProperty and NavigationProperty, this could also be imported as such, not by using the 'custom' property. For Description, Watermark, and s.o., it is however the right place, because they are **my** custom metadata, but displayName is breeze's also.

Comment: I know that the metadata collected from EF or NHibernate will not contain the displayName (but could also collect it from the [DisplayAttribute] for example) and that is why it was not a high priority, but let's say it would be nice :).

Comment: Actually there are a number of conditions where "DisplayName" is not part of the metadata (the one that comes to mind is that most of the 'true' OData services omit it, our WebApi implementation may capture it but it isn't really universal)